# Turn off semantic analysis for GLSL in KDevelop

Tags: glsl, syntax-highlighting, kdevelop

I ran into a not very pleasant problem: my GLSL shaders are defined by the analyzer as C++ code (nevertheless, KDevelop understands that it is GLSL (Service > Document type > 3D graphics > GLSL)!), Respectively, I see my shader as "full of errors". I would like to disable the semantic analysis for GLSL, but there is no information on the Internet about this.
[image]

Comment: That is an [unfixed bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=385113) in KDevelop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it as follows:

1. Right-click on the project
2. Configure project
3. Cppcheck
4. Include Directories
5. Ignored includes - here I pasted the path to the folder with shaders